# Firebase Podfile - CocoaPods was not able to update

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, updates

I am trying to update Firebase with Cocoapods to 3.0.2

On my first step I commented out the pod 'Firebase'

[image: Podfile]

Then I added it back and ran **pod install**

[image: Error Message]

Then it installed Firebase 2.5.1, so i ran **pod update** in order to get Firebase 3.0.2 as other questions on stack overflow imply.
But i always get this as a result:

[image]

So my question is what I have to do in order to get the update?
In my Podfile I have also uncommented the use_frameworks! But it didn't change anything.

I changed the Podfile to:

[image]

but still get an error message

[image]

Comment: dont go for update Pod version , because document is not perfect

Comment: how should the document be ?

Comment: They didn't update document . all document belongs to older version

Comment: pod 'Firebase', '~> 2.5.1' must must go for

Comment: I need help can u one favour for me. help related stack overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Firebase documents, as of version 3.x the Firebase pod has separate subspecs for each API.

To include Firebase using CocoaPods, you should write the following into your Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
```

**Edit:**

I failed to see that you didn't implement `source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'` into your Podfile, by adding that line at the top of your Podfile it should work.
I tested this Podfile and it works perfectly:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyTarget' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Database'
end
```

If this isn't working for you, update to the latest CocoaPods and try again.

[Upgrading from Firebase.com](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-ios#configure_your_app_numbered)

[CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/)

Comment: I have tried that, but always get: [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:  - `Firebase/Core` required by `Podfile`
- `Firebase/Core` required by `Podfile`

Answer (score 0):

I remove the podfile.lock.

Then pod install.

this works for me

Answer (score -1):

use pod search firebase

you can see:

-> Firebase (2.5.1)
   The official iOS client library for Firebase.
   pod 'Firebase', '~> 2.5.1'
   - Homepage: https://www.firebase.com/
   - Source:   https://cdn.firebase.com/ObjC/Firebase.framework-2.5.1.zip
   - Versions: 2.5.1, 2.5.0, 2.4.3, 2.4.2, 2.4.1.1, 2.4.1, 2.4.0, 2.3.3, 2.3.2,
   2.3.1, 2.3.0, 2.2.2, 2.2.1, 2.2.0, 2.1.2, 2.1.1, 2.1.0, 2.0.3, 2.0.2, 2.0.1,
   2.0.0, 1.2.3, 1.2.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.12, 1.1.11, 1.1.10, 1.1.9, 1.1.7,
   1.1.6, 1.1.5, 1.1.4, 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.9, 1.0.7, 1.0.5, 1.0.0
   [master repo]

so use:
pod 'Firebase', '~> 2.5.1'

Comment: This will not install Firebase 3.x, which is what the OP is requesting.